# function showDetails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show the HTML table data to a Detail form. But i am getting with the error `ReferenceError: showDetails is not defined`

Below is my HTML code & java script code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8 no-js">      <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie ie9 lte9 no-js">           <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html class="no-js">                       <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html class="no-js">                       <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>ELITE - A Powerfull Responsive Admin Theme</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; }
        .container { width: 35%; margin: 0 auto; }
        .search_box { padding: 1.5%; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12pt; }
    </style>


    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var driverdata = null;

    function showDetails(data){
       var form = $(this).parents('form:first');

       URL = "http://localhost:8888/drivers/find/"+id;
       driverdata = data;

       var cont = data;
    //alert(JSON.stringify(cont));




        $("#id").val(''+cont.id);
        $("#firstname").val(''+cont.firstName);
        $("#lastname").val(''+cont.lastName);
        $("#licenseid").val(''+cont.licenseId);
        $("#telephone").val(''+cont.telephone);
        $("#email").val(''+cont.email);




   }




    function doSearch() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
        var targetTable = document.getElementById('mytable');
        var targetTableColCount;

        //Loop through table rows
        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
            var rowData = '';

            //Get column count from header row
            if (rowIndex == 0) {
                targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
                continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
            }

            //Process data rows. (rowIndex >= 1)
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
                var cellText = '';

                if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
                    cellText = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).innerText;
                else
                    cellText = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;

                rowData += cellText;

            }

            //If search term is not found in row data
            //then hide the row, else show
            if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
                targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
            else
                targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
        }
    }




            var ajax_load = "loading...";

        var loadUrl = "TestPage.htm #dvContainer"; //load part of page
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //editableGrid.onloadJSON("editablegrid/examples/full/datasource/demo.json");  
            $('#tooltip').delay(2000).fadeIn(1200);
            $("#load_basic").click(function () {
                $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl, function (response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                        $("#dvError").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                }
                );
                return false;
            });


            window.onload = fun;
            function fun(){
                $("#dvAjax").html(ajax_load);


                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                    url: "http://localhost:8888/drivers/listAll", // Location of the service
                    success: function (data) {//On Successfull service call


var txtStr = '<table class="datatable"><thead><tr> <th>id</th> <th>firstName</th> <th>lastName</th> <th>licenseId</th> <th>telephone</th> <th>email</th> </tr></thead><tbody>';

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

     txtStr += '<tr class="gradeA"> <td><a class="edit_row" href="#tab2" onclick="showDetails(\''+data[i].id+'\');"><span>'+data[i].id+'</span></a></td> <td>'+data[i].firstName+'</td> <td>'+data[i].lastName+'</td> <td>'+data[i].licenseId+'</td> <td>'+data[i].telephone+'</td> <td>'+data[i].email+'</td> </tr>';

    //txtStr = txtStr + '<tr><td>' + json[i].id + '</td><td>' + json[i].firstName + '</td><td>' + json[i].lastName + '</td><td>' + json[i].licenseId + '</td><td>' + json[i].telephone + '</td><td>' + json[i].email + '</td><tr>';

     }

     txtStr += '</tbody></table>';
       $("#tab1").html(txtStr);

     $('.datatable').dataTable({
         'sPaginationType':'full_numbers'    
     });




     document.getElementById('somerow').innerHTML = txtStr;

                    },
                    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
                });


                return false;
            };



        });





        function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            if (xhr.responseText) {
                var err = xhr.responseText;
                if (err)
                    error(err);
                else
                    error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
            }
            return;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <form id="btnAjax" --> 


    <!-- <table id="mytable" -->

    <!-- </table-->

    </form>
</body>






                           <h2>View Drivers</h2>   </br>  


                                        <div class="table" id="tab1"> 

                                            <table class="basic-table" id="mytable">
                                                <thead>



                                         <tr>              
                                        <td><label >Id</label></td>
                                        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="Id" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label>FirstName</label></td>
                                        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="firstName" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>

                   </tr>               
                   <tr>  
                                        <td><label>LastName</label></td>
                                        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="lastName" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>

                                   </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                        <td><label >licenseId</label></td>
                                        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="licenseId" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label>Telephone</label></td>
                                        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="Telephone" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label>Email</label></td>
                                        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="Email" class="large" name="" value=""></td>


                                    </tr>




                                                </thead>


                                                </table>

                                                 <label for="search"> <strong>Search Box</strong>
                        </label> <td alihn="left"><input type="text" id="searchTerm" size="20" width="20" onkeyup="doSearch()" />

                                                </div>





                                <h2>Update Drivers</h2> </div> </br> </br>




                        <div class="tab" id="tab2">
                        <form id="search" action="search" name="search" class="horizontal-form">
                            <!-- Inputs -->
                            <!-- Use class .small, .medium or .large for predefined size -->



                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label >id</label></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="id" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label>firstName</label></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="firstname" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label>lastName</label></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="lastname" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label >licenseId</label></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="licenseid" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>

                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label>telephone</label></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="telephone" class="medium" name="" value=""></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label>email</label></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="email" class="large" name="" value=""></td>


                                    </tr>



                                    <tr>
                                       <td colspan="2"><button id="submit" type="button" onClick="Submit();" />Submit</button> or <a href="#">Cancel</a></td>


                                    </tr>





                            </fieldset>
                            </form>
                            </div>







                </html>
```

I want to show the HTML table data to a Detail form. Pls help me to pint out what mistake i have done. Thx..

Comment: Could you please make you question more specific. Because could not find what is **$("#detailview")** and **cont**. What is **cont** here? Is it a global object? and where do you call the function **ShowDetails()**

Comment: In My HTML page i have defined <li><a id="tableview" class="default-tab tooltip" href="#tab1" title="Sample tables">View</a></li>. I am calling the show details from  txtStr += '<tr class="gradeA"> <td><a class="edit_row" href="#tab3" onclick="showDetails(\''+json[i].id+'\');"><span>'+json[i].id+'</span></a></td> <td>'+json[i].firstName+'</td> <td>'+json[i].lastName+'</td> <td>'+json[i].licenseId+'</td> <td>'+json[i].telephone+'</td> <td>'+json[i].email+'</td> </tr>';

Comment: @Karthick88it Paste ALL of your relevant HTML AND JAVASCRIPT above or we'll never be able to point out where you are going wrong.

Comment: Leeish - pasted all the relevant codes above, pls have a look

Comment: Provide a demo: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive.

showDetails vs ShowDetails?

You want something like:

```
txtStr += '<tr class="gradeA"> <td><a class="edit_row" href="#tab2" onclick="showDetails('+json[i]');"><span>'+json[i].id+'</span></a></td> <td>'+json[i].firstName+'</td> <td>'+json[i].lastName+'</td> <td>'+json[i].licenseId+'</td> <td>'+json[i].telephone+'</td> <td>'+json[i].email+'</td> </tr>';

showDetails(obj){
    var cont = obj;
    //other code
}
```

I'm pretty sure that won't work that way as json[i] won't be appended like you'd want it to. I can't remember without testing if you can do it that way, but essentially that is what you want. Or you can grab the data using a `$this` approach on the event handler. Either way I would mark an answer as correct for this question and ask a new one as you now need help with a different issue.

Comment: Leeish- thanks for ur reply, I have changed to showDetails. But after that also i am not getting the html data to a detail tab. Any idea

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question, but just glancing at your code I think you want `$('#id').val(cont.id)` for starters. Also unless `cont` is a global variable it won't be accessible inside showDetails.

Comment: Leeish - I have tried this $("#id").val(cont.id) but getting with ReferenceError: cont is not defined

Comment: Exactly. Where does `cont` come from? You are not declaring it inside showDetails or passing it in. So unless it's a global variable it won't exist in the function.

Comment: I have declared inside the showDetails function var cont = data.contents; In-spite of that i am getting cont is undefined;

Comment: A: In the code you posted you are not showing any of this. B: Where does `data.contents` come from. Is that defined in the function or globally. If not it will be undefined as well. Paste the entire showDetails function, not just the part you think is important.

Comment: @Karthick88it, can you give me a sample value for your 'id', I mean the parameter

Comment: Leeish - I have pasted the entire code above both HTML & Javascript, ajax also.. I want to show the table data to a Update form. pls check with my entire code ..

Comment: Right off the bat. data is undefined. What do you think it is supposed to be?

Comment: @Leeish- data is nothing but the AJAX call will generate the data from the above URL & it will be displayed in the table. From this on-wards it is working fine. How to show the table data to a update form. pls help me in this

Comment: You are not understanding... I am looking through you code and `data` IS NOT A GLOBAL VARIABLE. Therefore, even IF you assign you `data` to your JSON result it will be undefined in `showDetails` as it is not global, AND not passed into the function. You do not understand variable scope. IN addition I don't even see where you assign data in an AJAX call. If `data` is empty then `cont` is empty because `cont` is based on `data`.

Comment: ok, i agree that i have nt declared data inside the ajax call. To make it work please guide me

Comment: I think u need to pass in your entire json object instead of just the id. then set cont to that. see my edit for a start

Comment: @Leeish Now i getting the values to the Update form, but getting as undefined values. Pls take a look at the new code.

Comment: @Karthick88it You need to post a new question, this one is too convoluted and too long. `data` is going to = `json[i].id` because that is what you passed in on the onClick. YOU NEED TO PASS IN THE ENTIRE OBJECT, not just the ID. I'm not answering any more on this thread, ask a new question and mark this one as resolved as its strayed to far from your original question and won't be helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough to give you a proper solution. I assume that `cont` is an global object and I have no idea about what is `$("#detailview").click();`. The very first important think you have to understand here is the elements to which you are trying to update are form fields (input types). As I know input type elements do not support for `.html()` function (correct me if I am wrong). Therefore if you want to assign some values for those form fields you have to use either `.attr()` or `.prop()` or `val()`. Try the following script.

```
function ShowDetails(id){    
   $("#id").val(''+cont.id);
   $("#firstName").val(''+cont.firstName);
   $("#lastName").val(''+cont.lastName);
   $("#licenseId").val(''+cont.licenseId);
   $("#telephone").val(''+cont.telephone);
   $("#email").val(''+cont.email);
}
```

But remember you have to sort it out what is `cont` here because still `cont` is vague here.

Comment: Now i am getting the values to the form, but getting it as Undefined values. Any idea behind this

Answer (score 0):

try with this and let me know is it working or not

```
        var ShowDetails = function(id){

        $("#id").html(''+cont.id);
        $("#firstName").html(''+cont.firstName);
        $("#lastName").html(""+cont.lastName);
        $("#licenseId").html(""+cont.licenseId);
        $("#telephone").html(""+cont.telephone);
        $("#email").html(""+cont.email);

        $("#detailview").click();
```

}

Comment: @Userhehehehe: tried with the above process also getting with the same problem, i have pasted my full code above. please have a look on it